# I'm working on a project using Nuxt.js for my frontend and Nuxt.js for my backend

Tags: nuxt.js

[usestorage not define](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YUaLp.png)
I have problem with my nuxt project.When loading data from json file it sends me usedatastorage not define.it worked before but when i did some more customizations it wont work.Can you please help me

Comment: If you do not provide a [repro] or some actual code, it's hard to help you.

Answer (score 0):

make sure to have useLocalStorage explicitly imported as mentioned in vueuse
[docs](https://vueuse.org/core/useStorage/#usestorage)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).